# Expected primary-expression before ‘long’

Tags: c++, c++17, greedy

What is the problem with my code ?

> prog.cpp: In function ‘void helper()’:
> prog.cpp:15:25: error: expected primary-expression before ‘long’
> `ans = ans + max(long long(0),vec[i]-i);`

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long
#define mod 1000000007

void helper(){
    ll n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<ll>vec(n);
    for(ll i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>vec[i];
    sort(vec.begin(),vec.end(),greater<ll>());
    ll ans=0;
    for(ll i=0;i<n;i++){
        ans = ans + max(long long(0),vec[i]-i);
        ans=ans % mod;
    }
    cout<<ans<<endl;
}

int main() {
    int test;cin>>test;
    while(test--){
        helper();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `max((long long)0, ven[i]-i);`, or `max( 0ll, vec[i]-i );`

Comment: *Please* inform whatever fiend is telling you and your classmates to use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` that they're doing you no favors and [it's a terrible habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Answer (score 2):

You can correct the error following one of these ways:
`(ll)0` or `(long long)0` or `0ll`

Comment: I followed these 3 steps also but it is not working , showing error

Comment: I ran code properly using above approach. Change code line : ans = ans + max( 0ll,vec[i]-i);
Can you please share what error you're getting after changing?

Answer (score 0):

The formal rule is that a constructor like type cast like `long long(0)` can only have a one word type name, and `long long` is two words. Oops, just doesn't work.

Using a proper C++ type cast like `static_cast<long long>(0)` *does* work. However, for a constant you could just use 0LL and avoid the cast altogether.